# Insecure NFS ports on OpenBSD server

Tags: mac-osx, nfs, openbsd

I have a OpenBSD 4.9 server running. Now I am trying to set up NFS shares on that server. I can set it up using secure ports. However it isn't possible to mount the shares from OS X without using the -P flag.

Sadly this isn't a valid option for me, because I cannot make my users mount the network devices with the terminal (or Disk Utility for that matter). They need to be able to use Finder.

So I need to turn of secure ports on the server side to make integration with OS X seamless.

Is it possible to do that in OpenBSD 4.9? (It seems to me that the options was removed since 4.3. But I'm currently not a OpenBSD expert.) How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the man page for the NFS daemon or conf file.

I'm not sure where you are stuck, my OSX users could use finder to go hunt for server shares, but they usually leave that to the sysadmin.

Comment: Now it was a while, and I switched to FreeBSD instead. However, when I investigated the issue it did seem impossible to set off secure ports in OpenBSD. Maby it works if building NFS-daemon from src.